# open3d voxel downsampling then dbscan cluster then approximately upscale clustering to the original image

Tags: python-3.x, dbscan, open3d

dbscan clustering is very memory intensive.
I'd like to downsample, calculate clusters, then approximately relate these calculated clusters to the original image.

This is the standard way to downsample is:

```
    # examples/Python/Basic/pointcloud.py

import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("../../TestData/fragment.ply")
    print(pcd)
    print(np.asarray(pcd.points))
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

    print("Downsample the point cloud with a voxel of 0.05")
    downpcd = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([downpcd])

    #Then this could be clustered via dbscan
    labels = np.array(
            downpcd.cluster_dbscan(eps=0.05, min_points=30, print_progress=True))
```

How would I then relate these labels back to the original PCD (pcd)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think that dbscan would work after down-sampling? If so I may give a try to an edited down-sampling methods that preserves the the info of which points are down-sampled to a grid point. Then if the grid point is a part of a cluster, then we can assume that all points that fall in that voxel is also a part of the same cluster. But I am worried about the result of the dbscan.

Comment: Yes, dbscan works better with smaller data sets. So, what you suggest is what I think is a strategy that would work, and is basically what I was trying to get at. I've been wondering if it does have a memory leak, though (larger and larger memory consumption, even when objects are deleted).

Comment: In Python you dont need to consider such things, memory leak etc., since it has garbage collector unless you really mess things up with recursion etc. But yeah, in C++ you must be very careful. I will post a naive implementation of my comment. I guess it can be written better, and I will try to improve it in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np


def voxel_downsampling(point_cloud, voxel_size):
    """
    Downsample an Open3D point cloud using voxel downsampling.

    Parameters:
    - point_cloud (open3d.geometry.PointCloud): Input point cloud.
    - voxel_size (float): Voxel size for downsampling.

    Returns:
    - open3d.geometry.PointCloud: Downsampled point cloud.
    """

    points_np = np.asarray(point_cloud.points)

    min_bound = np.min(points_np, axis=0)
    max_bound = np.max(points_np, axis=0)

    voxel_counts = np.ceil((max_bound - min_bound) / voxel_size).astype(int)

    voxel_indices = np.floor((points_np - min_bound) / voxel_size).astype(int)

    packed_indices = voxel_indices[:, 0] + voxel_indices[:, 1] * voxel_counts[0] + voxel_indices[:, 2] * voxel_counts[
        0] * voxel_counts[1]

    voxel_dict = {}
    voxel_to_point_index_dict = {}
    for i, index in enumerate(packed_indices):
        if index in voxel_dict:
            voxel_dict[index].append(points_np[i])
            voxel_to_point_index_dict[index].append(i)
        else:
            voxel_dict[index] = [points_np[i]]
            voxel_to_point_index_dict[index] = [i]

    downsampled_points = []
    tm_arr = []

    for points_in_voxel in voxel_dict.keys():
        downsampled_points.append(np.mean(voxel_dict[points_in_voxel], axis=0))
        tm_arr.append(points_in_voxel)
    downsampled_points = np.array(downsampled_points)

    downsampled_pc = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    downsampled_pc.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(downsampled_points)

    return downsampled_pc, voxel_to_point_index_dict, tm_arr


def upsample(pcd, pcd_downsampled, labels, voxel_to_point_index, tmp_arr):
    colors = {}
    for b in range(len(pcd_downsampled.points)):
        if labels[b] in colors:
            for pt in voxel_to_point_index[tmp_arr[b]]:
                pcd.colors[pt] = colors[labels[b]]
        else:
            color = np.random.rand(3)
            colors[labels[b]] = color
            for pt in voxel_to_point_index[tmp_arr[b]]:
                pcd.colors[pt] = colors[labels[b]]

    return pcd


import open3d as o3d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("fragment.ply")

    pcd_ds, voxel_to_point_index, tm_arr = voxel_downsampling(pcd, 0.01)

    # open3d_down = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.001)

    labels = np.array(
        pcd_ds.cluster_dbscan(eps=0.02, min_points=10, print_progress=True))

    up_pcd = upsample(pcd, pcd_ds, labels, voxel_to_point_index, tm_arr)

    max_label = max(labels)
    print(f"point cloud has {max_label + 1} clusters")

    o3d.io.write_point_cloud("output.ply", up_pcd)
```

I have used open3d fragments.ply file, and results are as follows:

[image: It could find 8 clusters with the given parameters.]

**A few notes**

- I implemented this voxel down sample some time ago, so if you catch any mistake please let me know.
- As I said this an heavy approach and I guess I can come up with a better solution using a custom data-set, but I currently don't have much time. I will try to improve when I can.
- I am still not sure if downsampling harms the dbscan or not, but you can play with parameters to have a better result.

Best

Comment: If you need a C++ version, let me know. I am not familiar with python much, so a C++ version probably will be much faster & easier to write for me.